# Compare variogram and variog function

Tags: r, geospatial, projection, proj, geor

I assumed (probably wrongly) that in the easiest cases the output of `variog` in the `geoR` package and `variogram` in the `sp` package would have been the same.

I have this dataset:

```
head(final)
lat     lon  elev seadist  tradist samples rssi
1 60.1577 24.9111 2.392     125 15.21606     200  -58
2 60.1557 24.9214 3.195     116 15.81549     200  -55
3 60.1653 24.9221 4.604     387 15.72119     200  -70
4 60.1667 24.9165 7.355     205 15.39796     200  -62
5 60.1637 24.9166 3.648     252 15.43457     200  -73
6 60.1530 24.9258 2.733      65 16.10631     200  -57
```

that is made of (I guess) unprojected data, so I project them

```
#data projection
#convert to sp object:
coordinates(final) <- ~ lon + lat #longitude first
library(rgdal)
proj4string(final) =  "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
UTM <- spTransform(final, CRS=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=35V+north+ellps=WGS84+datum=WGS84"))
```

and produce the variogram without trend according to the `gstat` library

```
var.notrend.sp<-variogram(rssi~1, UTM)
plot(var.notrend.sp)
```

[image: Plot gstat]

trying to get the same output in `geoR` I go with

```
UTM1<-as.data.frame(UTM)
UTM1<-cbind(UTM1[,6:7], UTM1[,1:5])
UTM1
coords<-UTM1[,1:2]
coords
var.notrend.geoR <- variog(coords=coords, data=rssi,estimator.type='classical')
plot(var.notrend.geoR)
```

[image: plot geoR]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points.

- `gstat` can work with unprojected data, and will compute the great-circle distance
- setting the "projection" to be `"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"` does not transform the data to a cartesian grid-based system (such as UTM)

What you are seeing in the output of `variogram` is the fact that is (sensibly) using great circle distances. If you look at the scale of the distance axis, you will see that the ranges are quite different, because `geoR` doesn't know (and can't account for) the fact you are not using a grid-based projection.

If you want to compare apples with apples use `rgdal` and `spTransform` to transform the coordinate system to an appropriate projection and then create variograms with similar specifications. (Note that gstat defines a cutoff ( the length of the diagonal of the box spanning the data is divided by three.)).

The empirical variogram is highly dependent on the definition of distance and the choice of binning. (see the brilliant [model-based geostatistics by Diggle and Ribeiro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387329072), especially chapter 5 which deals with this issue in detail.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifying answer. I understand that the binning and the cutoff are not the same, but they look now comparable to me. Right? Thank you for your time.

Comment: not to me: you use default values for both, and the plots make clear that the defaults differ. Control cutoff and bin width for both, use identical values, and then compare output numerically. I did this once, long ago, and found nothing that worried me.